# Xcode installed, but gcc/ g++ compilers are not found

Tags: macos, xcode, compile

I thought Xcode would come with these compilers. Can i download them manually? Where do i find them?

Comment: What's your operating system?

Comment: Mac OSX 10.6. 7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you downloaded the standard xcode for OSX it should already be installed to /usr/bin/gcc. If not, you need to reinstall it and follow the instructions on the screen.

Alternatively you can install gcc from your OSX dvd.

Comment: Xcode came from the appstore .. does not look like it modified any dir structure to add new programs.

Comment: http://pdb.finkproject.org/pdb/browse.php?summary=gcc has it but I would strongly recommend reinstalling xcode and making sure it's grabbing gcc like it should

Comment: Спасибі Blomkvis

Answer (score 1):

Xcode 4.3+ the 'Command Line Tools for Xcode' are optional.  They can be found here: https://developer.apple.com/downloads